# How to have arbitrary strings on the axis of a XY-diagram in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to have  strings like

```
  X     Y
Q1-07   2
Q2-07   6
Q3-07   8
Q4-07   6
Q1-08   1
```

on the X-axis in Excel. How can I see exact the 'Q1-07' etc. on the X-axis?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By its very nature, a scatter chart, or XY chart, has two numeric axes and numeric values for X and for Y. That's why it's called what it's called.

If you want categorical text values on the X axis, use a line chart. Line charts can be formatted to show just data markers, without any line in sight. The following screenshot shows a line chart with the series formatted to have no line, just markers.

[image]